# Multiple shortcuts for same functionality

Tags: shortcut-keys

I really like some of my shortcuts but I find at times there are other ways I would like to invoke the same shortcut.

For example:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>

Switches workspaces left/right respectively.

I want a mouse click to perform this same functionality.  My mouse wheel can go left/right and I want to map this to go left/right in my workspaces but I also want the keyboard shortcut to remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Compiz (chances are that you are) you can install *Advanced Desktop Effects Settings (ccsm)*, either from the Software Center or from the command line

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Now go to System-> Prererences-> CompizConfig Settings Manager.

Click on the Viewport Switcher icon. The window should change, go to the Desktop-bases Viewport Switching. Click on the buttons after Move Prev and Move Next (labeled Disabled on the screenshot). A new window will open, click enabled, another one will open, here you can select a mouse button for each action there, always or only when the mouse is in some screen places or when a special key is pressed.

[image: screenshot]

[image: another scrennshot]

Comment: Very verbose answer, much appreciated.  Intuitive too to assume I am using compiz.  :-)

Comment: Alternatively, you can install it via the Software Center, if we didn't assume that already.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add that you can also use your regular (vertical) mouse wheel axis to switch workspaces by adding Mouse4 and Mouse5 actions on the (left and right) screen edges. It's very intuitive and works very well. I can be configured in the `Rotate Cube` plugin.